# Folder file appears empty for few minutes in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, filesystem

I new to Ubuntu. Folder file appears empty for 5 to 10 minutes even though it contains file. After that the contents of the folder appear. It happens only on the partition where I install Ubuntu. Other partition are working perfectly.

The problem occurs only when browsing the filesystem in Nautilus. There's no delay when I access the directory via terminal.

Could you please help me?

[fdisk_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bodZH.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Folder file". Are you talking about a specific directory, or does this happen with every directory on your Ubuntu root partition when you use nautilus?

Comment: @Zanna It happen with every directory on ubuntu root partition.

Comment: Tell us how much RAM you have. How much swap? CPU specs. Please edit the question to include screenshots of the following terminal commands: `df` and `sudo fdisk -l` (lower case L). Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema, My System has 3 GB RAM & 6.5 GB swap memory and added screenshot.

Comment: I'm confused by your fdisk output. How did you get a **dos** disklabel type, and get 8 partitions? Did you do any disk manipulation other than just installing Ubuntu? Does everything work ok in Windows? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema I haven't done any disk manipulation & windows is working perfectly.

Comment: Log into the Guest account, and see if the problem occurs there also. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema In guess account it is working perfectly. Not sure why it is taking time in other account.

Comment: In terminal, type `rm ~/.config/nautilus/*` and then immediately log out. Log back in and see if the problem is fixed. Let me know. If it works, I'll write this into an answer that you can vote/accept as the solution. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema I tried this solution. Still facing same issue.

Comment: OK, try this. Open a Files window looking at your Home folder. On the keyboard, hit `control-h` to show hidden files. Rename `.config` folder to `.config.HOLD`, and `.cache` folder to `.cache.HOLD`. Immediately log out, and then log back in. It will recreate .config and .cache folder fresh. Some things might look different, or not work... but all we care about is seeing if the folder delay problem is gone. If it works, then something in one of those folders is causing the problem. If it doesn't work, move the new .config/.cache folders to the desktop, and rename the .HOLD back to normal.

Comment: @heynnema I tried your suggestion. Still same problem persist.

Comment: Did you logout after renaming the folders the first time? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I did

Comment: Well, **something** in your home folder is causing the problem. You can use the same technique of renaming/logout/login to narrow down the problem. You can also move (en mass) home folder items to the desktop, logout, login... and then move them back if they don't fix it. You're going to have to spend some time to chase this one down. Let me know what you find. Cheers, Al

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with Nautilus not the filesystem. Nautilus has had this bug before. Also double check that you don't have a .hidden file in that directory.. shouldn't be the case if eventually the directory's contents appear though.

> cd /path/to/folder/
>   ls -a #shows all including files hidden with .

Update your version of Nautilus, or refine your question and it's tags based on the fact that it is a Nautilus problem not ubuntu filesystem.